# Como crear una tabla donde se pueda guardar la factura de un rango de fechas

Tags: mysql, tablas, relaciones

Quiero crear una tabla donde pueda guardar una facturacion **por servicio** por medio de rango de fechas (A esto me refiero que habra una fecha inicial y final que seran escojidas por el usuario de una tabla de fechas).

Las tablas que tengo son las siguientes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver, hay un relacion de uno a muchos. De acuerdo a mi pregunta, intente crear esta tabla donde tomo los `ids` de la tabla `servicio_fecha` para poder guardar mi factura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto solucionaria mi problema porque tengo el `id1` y `id2` con el `nro_factura` pero como estoy utilizando el mismo `id` en la misma tabla, lo considere ineficiente. Por ello me gustaria saber **que  tabla crear para poder guardar mi factura, con el `servicio_fecha_id`**

¡Muchas gracias a todos!

Comment: Debería ser un solo campo de fecha y en la búsqueda trabajas con ese campo utilizando `BETWEEN` con las fechas que ingreses en los `textBox`.

Answer (score 1):

Como bien mencionaron, la fecha debería ser un atributo de la factura. Luego puede a través de consultas traer las facturas de un rango de fechas determinado.

En aplicaciones criticas con protocolos en tiempo real y mucha carga de transacciones, se suele implementar una tabla con el calendario y dentro de la factura podes colocar el id del calendario al que pertenece la factura.

Si lo que buscas es tener un periodo de facturación, puedes colocar fecha_inicio y fecha_fin como atributos dentro de la factura.

Por último, si deseas tener periodos de facturación fijos para un grupo de facturas, puedes crear una tabla periodos. La tabla periodos tendría ID_periodo, nombre_periodo (por ejemplo Nov-2020), fecha_desde, fecha_hasta, una descripción y cualquier información adicional que creas necesaria para el periodo. Luego dentro del registro de cada factura podes colocar como FK el id del periodo al que pertenece.

Las relaciones muchos a muchos solo se deberían utilizar si una factura esta en mas de un periodo, pero no debería ser el caso, ya que en la vida real solo tienen un periodo de facturación por factura.

Saludos.